# Repository usage in configureActionButtons (Sonata Admin Bundle)

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, sonata-admin, sonata

I am trying to inject doctrine service (if there is a way to inject `BoothTypeRepository` without Doctrine, that's also fine) into `configureActionButtons` and I can't find the way to inject nor doctrine or `BoothTypeRepository`.

```
public function configureActionButtons($action, $object = null): array
    {
        $list = parent::configureActionButtons($action, $object);;

        $handles = $this->getConfigurationPool()->getContainer()->get('doctrine.orm.entity_manager')->getRepository(BoothTypeRepository::class)->findAll();
        
        foreach($handles as $handle) {
            $list['new_' . $handle] = [
                'attr' => $handle,
                'template' => 'CRUD/button_new_booth_type.html.twig'
            ];
        }

        unset($list['new']);

        return $list;
    }
```

The Error which I got from the upper code

> An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template
> ("Class "App\Repository\BoothTypeRepository" sub class of
> "Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\Repository\ServiceEntityRepository" is
> not a valid entity or mapped super class.").

This is the namespace for `BoothTypeRepository` -> `namespace App\Repository;`

Answer (score 0):

Answer to this is in construct:
private BoothTypeRepository $boothTypeRepository;

```
public function __construct($code, $class, $baseControllerName, BoothTypeRepository $boothTypeRepository)
{
    parent::__construct($code, $class, $baseControllerName);

    $this->boothTypeRepository = $boothTypeRepository;
}
```

Then one don't need to use doctrine service ->

```
    $boothTypes = $this->boothTypeRepository->findAll();
```